# PySpark distinct funtion

Tags: pyspark

In a spark dataframe there are 10 columns, one of which is 'department'. Under the department column there are 10 distinct entries which I calculated with the distinct() function. I need to calculate the number of rows for each unique department entry now. What function should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of rows by groupBy() function.

```
df.groupBy('department').count()
```